# In gRPC, why does the parameter type of my generated newStub method requires com.google.protobuf.RpcChannel rather than ManagerChannel?

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

- I'm trying to use gRPC in my android project.
- I have generated my java class by protoc compiling.
- However, I notice that the generated method newStub requires `com.google.protobuf.RpcChannel` rather than `Managerio.grpc.ManagedChannel`. What should I do now?
  [image]

Comment: Please don't include images in questions. Images may not outlive questions and they inhibit copy-and-paste.

Comment: I'm familiar with gRPC but unfamiliar with Android|Java development. Looking at the Android [example](https://grpc.io/docs/platforms/android/java/quickstart/) on the gRPC site, suggests (!?) that the `io.grpc.android.AndroidChannelBuilder` is no longer (!?) used. The example (see [code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/38ef8d22d4d725245954c2ad7a557b42523e275c/examples/android/helloworld/app/src/main/java/io/grpc/helloworldexample/HelloworldActivity.java#L87)) uses `io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect something went wrong in the proto compilation phase. The generated code should have a static method `newStub(io.grpc.Channel channel)` that would accept your `ManagedChannel` as it extends from `Channel`.

Try going through the [Android quickstart](https://grpc.io/docs/platforms/android/java/quickstart/) to see the generated code there.

Comment: Same here; I am trying to generate the java class, but keep getting the wrong new stub implementation with com.google.protobuf.RpcChannel